# What software is for hosting my own private OCI/docker container/image registry or repository?

Tags: docker, containers, repository

Purely hypothetical question -- if I want to host my own private OCI/docker container repository, where I can push and pull over the network, what software would I use?

Do I also need another software to serve the website to access and manage packages visually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your first question about Docker registry options and not only?

[Nexus Repository OSS](https://www.sonatype.com/products/repository-oss-download) is one of the best free sefl-hosted solutions, in my point of view at least. I e.g. run it on my home server as docker container. Apart from using it as Docker Registry for docker images (i.e. for pushing your locally built docker images, storing your base images and pulling them) you can use it to manage your artifacts (i.e. store binaries of your built source code, pull them etc.).

> Do I also need another software to serve the website to access and manage packages visually?

No! It has also a [user Interface](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/using-the-user-interface) where you have a possibility to browse, view, edit etc.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.docker.com/registry/ is an option too.

My use case is slightly different (I want a pull-through cache) for which I'll need to use nexus probably, as the official docker registry image [has a gotcha](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/#gotcha).